# Django how to open file in FileField

Tags: django

I need to open a file saved in a FileField, create a list with the content of the file and pass it to the template. How can I open the file? I tried `with open(stocklist.csv_file.url, "wb")` but it gave me a "File not found" error. If I do this:

```
csv_file = stocklist.csv_file.open(mode="rb")
```

`csv_file` is `None`. However, there is a file. If I print `print("stocklist.csv_file.url: %s" % stocklist.csv_file.url)` I do get

stocklist.csv_file:  https://d391vo1.cloudfront.net/csv_pricechart/...ss7.csv

And if I go to the admin, I can download the file. So, how can I open a file saved in a `FileField`?

Comment: What is your storage back-end?

Comment: It is an AWS bucket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.open()` opens the file cursor but does not return it, since it depends of your storage (filesystem, S3, FTP...). Once opened, [you can use `.read()` to iterate over the file content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile).

```
stocklist.csv_file.open(mode="rb")
content = stocklist.csv_file.read()
stocklist.csv_file.close()
```

If you want to specifically work with file descriptor then you can use your storage functionality:

```
from django.core.files.storage import DefaultStorage
storage = DefaultStorage()
f = storage.open(stocklist.csv_file.name, mode='rb')
```